# $array[] = new stdClass; why array[] and not array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = [];

$array[] = new stdClass; //will return an array
$array = new stdClass; //will not
```

It seems odd as $array was declared as an array. forget the brackets in 
`$array = new stdClass;`
and `$array` is no longer an array.

Comment: `$var[] = new stdClass; //will return an array` 
`$var= new stdClass; //will not` is the name of the variable what's confusing you ?

Comment: _It seems **odd** as $array was declared as an array..._ no it doesn't, you override the array with `stdClass` and with `[]` you're appending new `stdClass` element to the array

Comment: And `$array = 'foo'` will turn `$array` into a string…  If `$array = []` makes  it an array, why would the same with another datatype do anything else?

Comment: And `$array = false` into a boolean

Comment: Just because the name of the variable is array, it doesn't mean that variable should only hold array. I can even declare `$string = [1,2,3];`

Answer (score 0):

`$array[] = new stdClass;` ADDS the new stdClass into the empty array `$array`.

`$array = new stdClass;` REPLACES the empty array `$array` with a new stdClass.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = ...
```

and

```
$array[] = ...
```

do very different things. The first either creates or overwrites a variable, the second appends to an existing one, assuming it exists.

So when you say

```
$array[] = new stdClass;
```

you're saying "append a new stdClass to my existing array". The variable is still an array, it just now has an extra element in it.

How a variable is first declared in PHP makes no difference to what happens when you overwrite it - the original is simply gone, and replaced with whatever you've assigned.